# Plot each day as a time serie on a hourly basis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a time series data frame (df) that has the information of a variable y for several days (registered hourly):

```
> df.head()

          Date           y         
1   2019-10-03 00:00:00 33  
2   2019-10-03 01:00:00 10  
3   2019-10-03 02:00:00 39  
4   2019-10-03 03:00:00 60  
5   2019-10-03 04:00:00 21
```

I want to plot each day as a single time series with the x-axis being the hours, i.e, I want to see y for each day (independently) on an hourly basis. If I have N days I would like to see the N time series on the sample plot, with the variable y on the y-axis and the hours on the x-axis. Is this possible?

If group my data on a daily basis I loose the hour information because of the sum function:

```
 > df_day = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='1D')).sum() 

       Date     y
0   2019-10-03 800
1   2019-10-04 899
2   2019-10-05 1020
3   2019-10-06 544
4   2019-10-07 321
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with dates and hours, aggregate sum and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df_day = (df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.date, df['Date'].dt.hour])['y']
            .sum()
            .unstack(fill_value=0))
print (df_day)
Date         0   1   2   3   4
Date                          
2019-10-03  33  10  39  60  21
```

Comment: Thanks, df_day.plot()  after your code got what I wanted.